# Keeping formatting when comparing cells / Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a daily report that I check by comparing it with the previous business days' results.  I paste each report into a worksheet and have a third worksheet with formulas to identify any changes.  The cells in the reporting sheet remain blank unless there is a change.  If there is a change then yesterdays' results are produced in the given cell with the difference along with the current days' numbers.

My problem is that the formatting mixes text and numbers and the results are, for example,

```
Today:
2123234.3423134
Yesterday:
1232412.3413243
```

Whereas I want them to read,

```
Today:
2,123,234.34
Yesterday:
1,232,412.34
```

Here is the code,

```
=IF(Today!AG23<>Yesterday!AG23,"Today: "&Today!AG23&" vs Yesterday: "&Yesterday!AG23," ")
```

I was thinking the answer was inserting the CELL function, I guess like this,

```
=IF(Today!AG23<>Yesterday!AG23,CELL("format", "Today: "&Today!AG23&"") vs CELL("format", Yesterday: "&Yesterday!AG23," ")
```

but, I can not get it to work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

DS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TEXT

```
=IF(Today!AG23<>Yesterday!AG23,"Today: "&TEXT(Today!AG23,"#,##0.00")&" vs Yesterday: "&TEXT(Yesterday!AG23,"#,##0.00"),"")
```

Comment: Accurate, thanks. I used TEXT to format the date comparison cells and should have figured it would work here.

Comment: @SozDaneron Please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.

Comment: I did but apparently because I have a reputation <15 it doesn't record publicly?

Comment: Not the down or up arrow/triangle.  The check mark below them. @SozDaneron

Comment: I didn't have post comment editing privileges  to add the @ but, I'll get there.  Much appreciated.